# How to get description of winhttp errors using error codes?

Tags: error-handling, winhttp

I am making a program that uses winhttp library. To handle various exceptions, I have created a header file. The error is thrown by using GetLastError() function which is passed to the exception class as DWORD variable. But I want to print the description of error and not just the  error number. I tried using FormatMessage function, its working for error 6 but not for others viz error 12002. I am using it like:

```
    WinHttpException(DWORD error)
    {
        LPTSTR lpszFunction = "Function";
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
        DWORD dw = error; 

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dw,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL );

        // Display the error message and exit the process

        lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 

        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
            LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
            TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
            lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 

        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

        m_message = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(lpDisplayBuf);
    }
```

I got this code from this Microsoft [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).. Is there any other way to do that? Or what arguments should i use in FormatMessage function to make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should call `LocalFree()` like in the Microsoft example you have linked to prevent two memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

WinHTTP error messages are contained in the `winhttp.dll` module and `FormatMessage()` function allows you to retrieve them using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` flag (as per [FormatMessage() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx)):

```
FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    GetModuleHandle(TEXT("winhttp.dll")),
    dw,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&lpMsgBuf),
    0, NULL);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>` call is needed here? I haven't needed it in my code or seen it used in other SO answers on this topic

Comment: @Hawkins That cast is not needed indeed, not sure why I put it there originally. I edited the answer and removed it.